# Swift: How to write custom slice function (Range / Sliceable / ForwardIndexType hell)

Tags: xcode, swift

XCode 6, Beta 5: enumerate(), Sliceable, and ForwardIndexType

I am trying to write slice functions that take closures instead of indices, but have landed in Slice and Range hell.  I want to find the first element passing the fitness closure's test, and return a slice from that element to the final element in the sequence etc.

My specific problem is that I need to pass the starting and ending indexes, but cannot bridge to or from Sliceable.Index aka ForwardIndexType to do this.  Here is what I have so far:

```
func slice<S:Sliceable>(s: S,
    #from: (S.Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> S.SubSlice {

    let l:Int = s.endIndex // error: cannot convert S.Index to Int
    for (i, e) in enumerate(s) {
        if (from(e)) {
            var f:S.Index = i  // error: cannot convert Int to S.Index
            return s[i..<s.endIndex] 
                // error: HalfOpenInterval<T> is not convertable to Range<S.Index>
        }
    }

    return s[s.startIndex..<s.endIndex]
}
```

I think there are multiple library bugs contributing to this:
 - Sliceable.Index is a ForwardIndexType, and Int should support this protocol
 - the enumerate function should take a Sliceable.Index type instead of Int

I did see in the Beta 5 release notes that Apple has reworked Slices and Ranges, but saw nothing actionable in that passage.

Any insight is appreciated - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `Int`. Just iterate over the indices:

```
func slice<S:Sliceable>(s: S,
    #from: (S.Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> S.SubSlice {

        for i in s.startIndex ..< s.endIndex {
            if from(s[i]) {
                return s[i..<s.endIndex]
            }
        }

        return s[s.endIndex..<s.endIndex]
}
```

or:

```
func slice<S:Sliceable>(s: S,
    #from: (S.Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> S.SubSlice {

        var i = s.startIndex
        while i != s.endIndex && !from(s[i]) {
            i = advance(i, 1)
        }
        return s[i..<s.endIndex]
}
```

Example:

```
let a = [2, 7, 3, 1, 9]
let b = slice(a) { $0 == 3 }
println(b) // [3, 1, 9]
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was foiled by enumerate, which now seems useless.  I have had a hard time parsing the nuances of ranges and slices, and Beta 5 just changed that again.

Answer (score 0):

Or better,

```
for i in indices(s) {
    if from(s[i]) {
        return s[i..<s.endIndex]
    }
}
return s[s.endIndex..<s.endIndex]
```